# Providing an Integer parameter to the magic command fs

Tags: databricks

Trying to implement the below command but there is a type mismatch.

```
%fs head dbfs:/databricks-datasets/README.md 6000

Error:
notebook:1: error: type mismatch;
 found   : String("6000")
 required: Int
println(dbutils.fs.head("dbfs:/databricks-datasets/README.md", "6000")) // SAFE COMMAND FROM MACRO
```

Is there no way that I can provide integer parameters at the magic command level?

Answer (score 0):

There is a way. This works:

```
%fs head dbfs:/databricks-datasets/README.md --maxBytes=6000
```